# How to access and manipulate each chunk in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I created the following chunks

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
df = pd.read_sql_query(address,cnxn,chunksize=10000000)
```

Now, I want to access each chunk and do some analysis on them
The following method works on small datasets, but again the list growing bigger and bigger and it gives memory error on large datasets:

```
for chunk in df:
    dfl.append(chunk)
dfl[0] # here I can access the first dataframe in chunks
```

Is there any other way to access and retrive data when needed?
For example, I want to do the following manipulation on spesific chunk:
`chunk1['adress'] = chunk1['adress'].str.lower()`

How would I do that?

Comment: If you have not enough memory to contain the whole data, you should use `Dask` or `PySpark`. Read https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-sql.html

Comment: Can you give an example of using dask?

Comment: After you processing DataFrame what is next step? Create csv?

Comment: No, I just want to do some analysis on each dataframes

Comment: Could you tell us more about the criterion that you use to split your DataFrame into chunks? I imagine that you have a column that you can use to group the data. In that case, you can probably do something like `df.groupby("column_name").str.lower()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(address,cnxn,chunksize=10000000)
for chunk in df:
    #your code for analyze
    chunk['adress'] = chunk['adress'].str.lower()
    ...
    print (chunk)
```

Comment: It will again give an error since the data is above 80 mn records, so what I want is accessing a spesific chunk, like chunk[0], chunk[1] etc

Comment: is there any other way to do that on a spesific chunk?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan - If need only analyze solution above working well. there is no append, so you can obly print analyze.

Comment: It works and do not throw a memory error, but takes too much time to do even simple analysis. My code is still running since yesterday. Do you know any other way to speed up this process? I read about vaex, but I dont know if it can be used in my case

Comment: @LeylaAlkan - I think best is create new question with vaex tag and code for processing used now and I hope get solution. I dont know waex, so no idea.